# spring-cloud-dataflow UI timezone use only UTC?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I use spring-cloud-dataflow(scdf) in the k8s environment.
The timezone was modified by changing the application property as follows.
`spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.environmentVariables=JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Tokyo`

Database timezone is also set to Asia/Tokyo.
It works well.

However, in scdf dashboard, it is considered UTC and shows +9 at the stored time.

How can I set the dashboard default timezone?

GOAL: set timezone to scdf dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always want to store times in UTC and let the dashboard display in your browser timezone. If you require an option to select the timezone I would suggest logging an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues)